# Unable to type in the text input in react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am creating a login page in react-native and redux. When ever I try to update the value of password and email using action, I am unable to type in my text input. Its kinda autodeleted when ever i try to type. Can some one help me out to solve this.

repo link: https://github.com/udhay1415/RN-MANAGER

Comment: You haven't provided any code, any repo or anything. We need some code to help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/udhay1415/RN-MANAGER

Comment: 1. https://github.com/udhay1415/RN-MANAGER/blob/master/src/components/LoginForm.js#L22

2. https://github.com/udhay1415/RN-MANAGER/blob/master/src/components/LoginForm.js#L32
On both these line you have a typo maybe, it should be onChangeText not OnChangeText, lowercase 'o'.

Comment: thanks a lot @Shubhnik Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake when the TextInput value is linked to your component's state.

Make sure to use it like this:

```
<TextInput
        ...
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
```

Then if you want to change the TextInput value from anywhere else, you just have to use setState.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue but it was a typo.

Instead of writing :

```
<Input 
        label = 'Password'
        value={password}  
        onChangeText={(newPassword)=> setPassword(newPassword)}
/>
```

I wrote:

```
<Input 
        label = 'Password'
        value={password}  
        onChangeTex={(newPassword)=> setPassword(newPassword)}
/>
```

For me, it worked.

Comment: `onChangeTex` instead of `onChangeText`?